# How to use Udev correctly to call lshw ？

Tags: bash, centos, udev

Env:

- CentOS 6.9 in VM 12 Pro

I want to automatically get some hardware information after inserting a USB drive.

When I use Udev rules to call a script containing the lshw tool, I accidentally get some empty files.

For example:

When I execute the script directly, I can get the correct result.A HTML file that contains hardware information.

```
#!/bin/bash
lshw -html > /root/test.html
```

But when use udev rule named `11-add-usb.rules` to call script.I can only generate an empty file.

```
ACTION!="add", GOTO="end"
KERNEL=="sd[a-z][0-9]", RUN+="/root/test.sh %k"
LABEL="end"
```

Comment: [Please don't post images of the code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Just to let you know - https://unix.stackexchange.com/ You can also ask here more related to unix